# How to control an image from getting off the screen (Using Timer & Random) Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, random, timer

I am trying to make the ball image to move randomly within the relativeLayoutGame layout using Timer and Random class. Please would you mind help me How to make sure the ball stay moving within the layout ( Not going off it ).

[image]

```
    public void hide(View view){


    final Timer tmr = new Timer();
    final ImageView imgBall = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgBall);
    final RelativeLayout relativeLayGame = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.relativeLayGame);


    final float gameLayoutWidth = relativeLayGame.getWidth();
    final float gameLayoutHeiht = relativeLayGame.getHeight();


    tmr.schedule(
            new TimerTask() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    Random rnd = new Random();
                    int xRnd = rnd.nextInt(996)-996;
                    int yRnd = rnd.nextInt(1358)-1358;

                    if(xRnd == gameLayoutWidth || yRnd == gameLayoutHeiht){
                        xRnd = rnd.nextInt(996)-996;
                        yRnd = rnd.nextInt(1358)-1358;
                        imgBall.animate().xBy(xRnd).yBy(yRnd);
                    }else {
                        imgBall.animate().xBy(xRnd).yBy(yRnd);
                    }

                }
            },0,2000
    );



}
```